# Insert incrementing event_ids for every sequence_id counting up from 1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a big Oracle SQL table and I need an incrementing id counting up for every sequenceId. But if the session number is the same, it has the same id! I think it's easier to understand with an example:

Current situation:

| Timestamp | ItemId | PersonId | Session | SequenceId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-14 16:15:21 UTC | 5865526 | 465496 | 51c95e97-ffd6 | 1 |
| 2020-01-14 16:25:35 UTC | 5769989 | 465496 | 61c95e97-ffd6 | 1 |
| 2020-01-14 16:27:31 UTC | 5865524 | 465496 | 61c95e97-ffd6 | 1 |
| 2020-01-14 18:27:31 UTC | 5865524 | 465496 | 71c95e97-ffd6 | 1 |
| 2019-11-04 15:28:57 UTC | 5240 | 1120748 | 31c95e97-ffd6 | 2 |
| 2019-12-28 14:32:56 UTC | 5881337 | 1180452 | 41c95e97-ffd6 | 3 |

Needed:

| Timestamp | ItemId | PersonId | Session | SequenceId | EventId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-14 16:15:21 UTC | 5865526 | 465496 | 51c95e97-ffd6 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-14 16:25:35 UTC | 5769989 | 465496 | 61c95e97-ffd6 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-14 16:27:31 UTC | 5865524 | 465496 | 61c95e97-ffd6 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-14 18:27:31 UTC | 5865524 | 465496 | 71c95e97-ffd6 | 1 | 3 |
| 2019-11-04 15:28:57 UTC | 5240 | 1120748 | 31c95e97-ffd6 | 2 | 1 |
| 2019-12-28 14:32:56 UTC | 5881337 | 1180452 | 41c95e97-ffd6 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: I need them as a table but I can create a new table with the query (CREATE TABLE xy AS SELECT ...) :D @Austin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with t as  (
  2  select 'a' sessionid, 1 sequenceid from dual union all
  3  select 'b' sessionid, 1 sequenceid from dual union all
  4  select 'b' sessionid, 1 sequenceid from dual union all
  5  select 'c' sessionid, 1 sequenceid from dual union all
  6  select 'e' sessionid, 2 sequenceid from dual union all
  7  select 'e' sessionid, 2 sequenceid from dual union all
  8  select 'g' sessionid, 2 sequenceid from dual union all
  9  select 'h' sessionid, 3 sequenceid from dual union all
 10  select 'i' sessionid, 3 sequenceid from dual union all
 11  select 'j' sessionid, 3 sequenceid from dual union all
 12  select 'k' sessionid, 3 sequenceid from dual
 13  )
 14  select
 15    t.*,
 16    dense_rank() over ( partition by sequenceid  order by sessionid ) as s
 17  from t;

S SEQUENCEID          S
- ---------- ----------
a          1          1
b          1          2
b          1          2
c          1          3
e          2          1
e          2          1
g          2          2
h          3          1
i          3          2
j          3          3
k          3          4

11 rows selected.
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU!! Your query saved my life! Thank you very much!